# Linq EF group by to get latest entries into list of objects

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to move from simple SQL to EF.

But there are some complex queries(joins) that it seems to hard to generate the linq for.

At first I tried to use sqltolinq tool to generate the linq but it gives error as some of the things are not supported in the query.

here is the linq:

```
var entryPoint = (from ep in dbContext.tbl_EntryPoint
                 join e in dbContext.tbl_Entry on ep.EID equals e.EID
                 join t in dbContext.tbl_Title on e.TID equals t.TID
                 where e.OwnerID == user.UID
                 select new {
                     UID = e.OwnerID,
                     TID = e.TID,
                     Title = t.Title,
                     EID = e.EID
                 });
```

The table entry has many entries that I would like to group and get the latest for each group. But then I would need to select into a view model object which will be bind to gridview.

I dont know where I can implement the logic to group by and get the latest from each and be able to get values from join table into viewModel object.

somewhere I need to add

```
group entry by new
                    {
                        entry.aID,
                        entry.bCode,
                        entry.Date,
                        entry.FCode
                    }
                    into groups
select groups.OrderByDescending(p => p.ID).First()
```

in the above linq to retrieve latest from each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert `group by` right after the joins:

```
var query = 
    from ep in dbContext.tbl_EntryPoint
    join e in dbContext.tbl_Entry on ep.EID equals e.EID
    join t in dbContext.tbl_Title on e.TID equals t.TID
    where e.OwnerID == user.UID
    group new { ep, e, t } by new { e.aID, e.bCode, e.Date, e.FCode } into g
    let r = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.e.ID).FirstOrDefault()
    select new
    {
        UID = r.e.OwnerID,
        TID = r.e.TID,
        Title = r.t.Title,
        EID = r.e.EID
    };
```

The trick here is to include what you need after the grouping between `group` and `by`.

However, the above will be translated to `CROSS APPLY` with all joins included twice. If the grouping key contains fields from just one table, it could be better to perform the grouping/selecting the last grouping element first, and then join the result with the rest:

```
var query = 
    from e in (from e in dbContext.tbl_Entry
               where e.OwnerID == user.UID
               group e by new { e.aID, e.bCode, e.Date, e.FCode } into g
               select g.OrderByDescending(e => e.ID).FirstOrDefault())
    join ep in dbContext.tbl_EntryPoint on e.EID equals ep.EID
    join t in dbContext.tbl_Title on e.TID equals t.TID
    select new
    {
        UID = e.OwnerID,
        TID = e.TID,
        Title = t.Title,
        EID = e.EID
    };
```

Comment: Thank you. you are a star @Ivan.. This works perfect. just another quick question though. If I would like to add a logic in the select new attributes such as UID = e.ownerID+RanddomNumber(). I guess this would be not allowed here as the query runs against the database. But what would be the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: You are right - EF does not support functions that cannot be translated to SQL. But you can always say `query.AsEnumerable().Select(e = > new { ... })` and put whatever you like inside the new `select`, since the rest will be executed in LINQ to Objects context, where everything that compiles is supported.